# How to efficiently work around the seemingly repetitive "у меня", "у нее", "у меня"?

Tags: стилистика

In conversation, I just said:

> Почему-то **у меня** это вылетело из головы, а **у нее** и подавно... Хорошо, что **у меня** в памяти все воскресло вовремя!

The context of the conversation was: *We've each been so busy lately that it completely slipped our minds that we were expecting a visitor later on this afternoon.*

In hindsight, I get the impression that  the three consecutive "у меня/нее" stylistically leave something to be desired, but I can't figure out how to work round that without making the sentence ambiguous.

How can this idea be effectively paraphrased without repeating the "у + pronoun"?

Comment: Because in this particular case one person is a male and the other is a female, you can drop it altogether and go with "хорошо что вовремя [всё] вспомнил".

Comment: you are wrong - it's completely fine to be repetitive in that way.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence sounds good as is (a possible version of its second part: *... не говоря уже о ней*.) The second sentence can be changed into:

> Хорошо, что я вовремя всё вспомнил!
>
> Хорошо, что всё вспомнилось в нужный момент!

Answer (score 2):

This repetition is not that bad, especially in spoken language. Russians do like repeating. There is even a manner of speech called "beads", which is broadly used in church (and Stalin was fond of it):

> Мы пойдём на рыбалку. На рыбалку мы пойдём с утра. На рыбалку мы пойдём на речку. На речку мы пойдём втроём ...

But if you still want to avoid repeating, you may just use names or other designations:

> Почему-то **у меня** это вылетело из головы, а у **Лены** и подавно... Хорошо, что **я вспомнил** вовремя!

P.S. "*у меня в памяти все воскресло*" is too dramatic for casual situations, it is better to use "*у меня в памяти все всплыло*".